# google calendar html

Tags: java, android

I've noticed that google calendar doesn't allow me to put html into the body of a new event.  Is there any workaround to prevent the html from getting stripped out when putting into a google calendar event?  I'm using the google calendar java api for an android application.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any web app that accepts arbitrary input from the user has to either strip all tags or otherwise take measures to sanitize the input. Sounds like Google went for the former.

The reason is that with one incorrectly specified tag you can corrupt the entire page not only for yourself but for anyone that views that page. Another approach is to allow non-HTML tags to be used for markup. that's what this site does.

I know this didn't answer your question, but I thought it might help to have an understanding about why they are doing it.

Comment: Thanks Farble, It does make sense.  I just had high hopes that I might be able to put some nice content into a calendar entry but it seems like there is no way to do it.  Oh well.